# copy the entire svn repository with history

Tags: svn

I have few svn repositories from one service provider which I want to move to  another service provider, the repository should also have earlier commits/history along with the code.

I have searched many options but nothing is working for me.

I would require urgent help on this.

Comment: Does the other provider not offer an "import" option? There's svnsync but it cannot properly 'fake' old commits without the server's help.

Comment: basically the source is providing .dump but now the destination ( bitbucket.org) does not have mechanism to import it.

Comment: Ah, but Bitbucket doesn't support SVN in the first place, does it? On the other hand, if you plan on converting the repository to Git or Hg, the converted output can be just pushed to the new server.

Answer (score 1):

**Remote SVN-source -> Remote HG-source**

- `svnrdump dump URL/OF/SVN/REPO/ROOT > repo.dump` or load provided by hosting dump-file
- `svnadmin load /PATH/TO/LOCAL/SVN/REPO < repo.dump`
- `svnserve -r ..//PATH/TO/LOCAL/SVN/REPO`
- Add hgsubversion extension to Mercurial (global config)
- `cd SOMEPATH; hg clone svn://localhost/REPO`
- `hg push URL/OF/HG/REPO`

**BEWARE!!!**

Dirty draft, may contain some not fundamental mistakes, must be considered as concept. pp. 4-5 can be replaced by using [Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Subversion)